# Clean install of Strapi/Next.js starter throws errors on preview mode

Tags: next.js, strapi, i18next

I am running a clean install of the [strapi-starter-next-corporate](https://github.com/strapi/strapi-starter-next-corporate) starter app. When I try to access a preview of the unpublished "secret" page, I get this error:

```
[develop:frontend] error - ReferenceError: locale is not defined
[develop:frontend]     at preview (C:\Users\username\Projects\projectname\frontend\.next\server\pages\api
\preview.js:36:5)
[develop:frontend]     at Object.apiResolver (C:\Users\username\Projects\projectname\frontend\node_module
s\next\dist\server\api-utils.js:101:15)
[develop:frontend]     at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
[develop:frontend]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
[develop:frontend]     at async DevServer.handleApiRequest (C:\Users\username\Projects\projectname\fronte
nd\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:775:9)
[develop:frontend]     at async Object.fn (C:\Users\username\Projects\projectname\frontend\node_modules\n
ext\dist\server\next-server.js:666:37)
[develop:frontend]     at async Router.execute (C:\Users\username\Projects\projectname\frontend\node_modu
les\next\dist\server\router.js:205:32)
[develop:frontend]     at async DevServer.run (C:\Users\username\Projects\projectname\frontend\node_modul
es\next\dist\server\next-server.js:846:29)
[develop:frontend]     at async DevServer.run (C:\Users\username\Projects\projectname\frontend\node_modul
es\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js:355:20)
[develop:frontend]     at async DevServer.handleRequest (C:\Users\username\Projects\projectname\frontend\
node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:292:20) {
[develop:frontend]   page: '/api/preview'
[develop:frontend] }
[develop:backend ] [2022-02-09 09:48:13.162] http: POST /graphql (9 ms) 400
[develop:frontend] TypeError: Cannot read property 'global' of undefined
[develop:frontend]     at getGlobalData (C:\Users\username\Projects\projectname\frontend\.next\server\pag
es\_app.js:628:22)
[develop:frontend]     at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
[develop:frontend]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
[develop:frontend]     at async Function.MyApp.getInitialProps (C:\Users\username\Projects\projectname\fr
ontend\.next\server\pages\_app.js:249:24)
[develop:frontend]     at async Object.loadGetInitialProps (C:\Users\username\Projects\projectname\fronte
nd\node_modules\next\dist\shared\lib\utils.js:69:19)
[develop:frontend]     at async Object.renderToHTML (C:\Users\username\Projects\projectname\frontend\node
_modules\next\dist\server\render.js:314:17)
[develop:frontend]     at async doRender (C:\Users\username\Projects\projectname\frontend\node_modules\ne
xt\dist\server\next-server.js:1149:38)
[develop:frontend]     at async C:\Users\username\Projects\projectname\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\se
rver\next-server.js:1241:28
[develop:frontend]     at async C:\Users\username\Projects\projectname\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\se
rver\response-cache.js:64:36
```

My preview url:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/preview?secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&slug=secret
```

I also tried:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/preview?secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&slug=/secret
```

My .env file for my next app:

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_API_URL=http://localhost:1337
PREVIEW_SECRET=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

My .env file for my strapi app:

```
FRONTEND_URL=http://localhost:3000
FRONTEND_PREVIEW_SECRET=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

The I18 plugin and the preview code seem not to be totally integrated. Has anyone else encountered this?

Windows 11
Node.js v14.18.3

Answer (score 2):

I think that you found a bug. The reason is that strapi-starter-next-corporate uses `locale` inside API route `/frontend/pages/api/preview.js`. Next.js does not support locale inside API route. You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/21798).