# How do I install a previous commit of a node.js starter app in Github?

Tags: node.js, git, github, next.js, strapi

I want to use a [starter app](https://github.com/strapi/strapi-starter-next-corporate) for my strapi/next.js project, but because the latest version in the master branch has a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71115745/clean-install-of-strapi-next-js-starter-throws-errors-on-preview-mode), I would like to use a [previous commit](https://github.com/strapi/strapi-starter-next-corporate/tree/0bb57fd39acce7b9ae86900688f0f420f069b7d8/starter) of the starter instead.

I thought it would make sense to download the previous version from GitHub and install the previous starter from my local machine, but I'm not sure how to do that. And maybe this isn't the best way to go about it anyway.

What would be the best way to install a starter from a past commit?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Strapi Corporate Template Readme](https://github.com/strapi/strapi-template-corporate#usage) file you can install the desired template by providing it's respective URL.

> ###### Using Yarn
>
> yarn create strapi-app my-app-name --template https://github.com/strapi/strapi-template-corporate
>
> ###### Or using NPM
>
> npx create-strapi-app my-app-name --template https://github.com/strapi/strapi-template-corporate

Hence, you can try providing it the URL of your desired commit and it should work just fine.

###### Using Yarn

```
yarn create strapi-app strapi-starter-templ --template https://github.com/strapi/strapi-starter-next-corporate/tree/0bb57fd39acce7b9ae86900688f0f420f069b7d8/starter
```

###### Using Npm

```
npx create-strapi-app my-app-name --template https://github.com/strapi/strapi-starter-next-corporate/tree/0bb57fd39acce7b9ae86900688f0f420f069b7d8/starter
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I tried the commands, and both of them fail. I also tried removing the trailing /starter from the github url. The error I get is: Template installation failed: Command failed: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /q /s /c "npm view https://github.com/strapi/strapi-starter-next-corporate/tree/0bb57fd39acce7b9ae86900688f0f420f069b7d8 name version --silent"
Any idea why it isn't working?

Comment: It appears that the above commands don't work with Strapi v4, though they should work with v3. https://github.com/strapi/strapi-template-corporate/issues/14

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question because I don't want to change templates. I want to use a past version of a starter. Starters use templates but are not themselves templates.

Comment: Hi @J7stin I've not changed the template. I've used the URL of the previous commit you attached in the question. Also, I tried hitting the command and it asks me to choose installation type. So I think the command works fine.
`npx create-strapi-app my-app-name --template https://github.com/strapi/strapi-starter-next-corporate/tree/0bb57fd39acce7b9ae86900688f0f420f069b7d8/starter
npx: installed 104 in 16.393s
? Choose your installation type (Use arrow keys)
❯ Quickstart (recommended) 
  Custom (manual settings)`

Comment: I hope you're not entering the command along with the `$` symbol at the start.